# Can't get BASH script to wait for PID

Tags: linux, bash

I am building a script to make my life easier when setting up servers.

I am having a issue with this line:

```sh
# Code to MV/CP/CHOWN files (working as intended)
sudo su $INSTALL_USER -c \
    "sh $SOFTWARE_DIR/soa/Disk1/runInstaller \
    -silent -response $REPONSE_LOC/response_wls.rsp \
    -invPtrLoc  $ORA_LOC/oraInsta.loc \
    -jreLoc /usr/java/latest" >&3
SOA_PID = pgrep java
wait $SOA_PID
# Code below this which requires this be completed before execution.
```

I am trying to get my script to wait for the process to complete before it continues on.

The script executes, but instead of waiting, it continues on, and the execution of the installer runs after the script finishes. I have other installer pieces that need this part installed before they start their own process, hence the wait.

I've tried using $! etc, but since this piece get executing by a separate user, I don't know if that would work.

Thanks for any assistance.

Comment: Run your script though http://shellcheck.net and come back when you have fixed the errors it reports :-)

Comment: `SOA_PID = pgrep java` needs to be something like `SOA_PID=$(pgrep java)` -- i.e. no spaces, and call a sub-process (the $(...) bit) ... And you probably need to deal with multiple java processes running, so `grep` returning multiple values.....

Comment: You're not running the script in the background, so there's nothing to wait for. And a process can only wait for its own children -- you can't wait for a process that's being run by `su`, because it's a child of the shell that `su` runs, not a child of your original shell.

Comment: @andlic That site is not book marked. Thanks. Testing out suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

The command `SOA_PID = pgrep java` should result in an error.

Try to capture the PID like this:

```
SOA_PID=$( pgrep java ) || exit
```

The `|| exit` forces an exit if `pgrep` does not return a value,
preventing nonsense happening further on.
An alternative would be to rely on `wait` to return immediately,
but it's better to be explicit.

When using this in a function you'd use `|| return` instead, depending
on circumstances.

Comment: @sorontar Incorporated that into the answer, it's the style I prefer anyway.